# If webbrowser1.url is not iqual then

Tags: vb.net

Hi hello i have google to try to get this info but i dint get any example for it
i need to check web a webbrowser is change from link
some thing like that

```
if webbrowser1.url is not iqual then 
   do that
end if
```

Is there any way to me to do that?

Comment: english language uses "equal" not "iqual" just store the correct url in a variable and check: `If webbrowser1.url <> myurl then`

Comment: Tank you very much for the great help i only needed that to finish my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a VB.Net answer since @raBinn suggested C# and also not checking browser URL

```
Dim MyUrl As String = "http://mywebsite.com"
If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString <> MyUrl Then
    'Going to an authorized place
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(MyUrl)
End If
```

Comment: Tanks the code now there is no error but well what i try to do is wen the url is changed the close this form and open the main form like this example but its seems not work because the form its not close at all

Comment: Private Sub google_adsense_code_Closing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing

        Dim MyUrl As String = "http://mediaads.eu/proxy/index.php?q=aHR0cDovL21lZGlhYWRzLmV1L2ZlYXR1cmVkX3B1Yi5odG1s&hl=2ed"
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        Me.Visible = False
        e.Cancel = True

        If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString <> MyUrl Then

            Me.Hide()
            Form1.Show()
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: you need to use the [DocumentCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
Uri uri1 = new Uri(url1);
Uri uri2 = new Uri(url2);

// Check urls
if (uri1.AbsolutePath == uri2.AbsolutePath)
{
    // Urls match
}
```

maybe this link could help you.

Good luck !!

Comment: Tanks for the help but how can i do this for only check one url?

Comment: Because i dont know the second url is ramdomized url and its never the same

Comment: with the event WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted Event you could check what url is loaded in WebBrowser control. Thanks  Mederic

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
    //Check if page is fully loaded or not
    if (this.webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        return;
    else
        //Action to be taken on page loading completion
}

Comment: @raBinn no problem but remember in vb.net there's no "{}" for defining functions or subs or methods. Apart for arrays

Comment: It's true, excuse me, it's c #. If you want to translate I usually use: http://converter.telerik.com/